# Offset the new angle based on the current angle that calculated by accelerometer and gyroscope values

Tags: c

At first, I'm using the icm20602 motion sensor to get the Roll and Pitch angle on my board, these angles are quite stable and good to observe. However, these angles are just right for a few situations such as Z's vertical, Y's vertical and X's vertical. Technically, the board is not always in equilibrium perhaps it will lean forward or backward,.. so I did the auto_offset function which automatically offset the new value turned into (0,0,0) from the current value (example: 20,-300,-8511). Fortunately, the initial offset value was correct in many sides but now the angle is not accurate.

My basic steps follow as :

1. Read the Accelerometer and Gyroscope values from sensor : OK
2. Calculate the Roll and Pitch angle based on these toward values : OK
3. The circuit board can rotate counterclockwise and clockwise from 0-360 degrees : OK
4. Before auto_offset:

   - the accelerometer : x=-78 y=-148 z=8036
   - the angle : Roll= 80.6    Pitch= 5.3 (Z: vertical)
5. After auto_offset:

   - the accelerometer : x=-115 y=-181 z=-239
   - the angle : Roll= -0.0    Pitch= -0.0 (Z: vertical)
6. But when I rotate this board :

   - clockwise-> the angle : OK
   - counterclockwise -> the angle : wrong values.(the real angle is 90.0 degrees but it shows 25.0 degrees or nearly)

I hope someone will help me to solve it. Thank you so much

```
void icm20602_auto_offset(IMU_DATA_T *imuData)
{
    int32 accTemp[3] = {0};
    int32 gyroTemp[3] = {0};
    uint16 i;
    size_t offset;

#if 1
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        inv_icm20602_poll_sensor_data_reg(imuData);   // read raw data from register
        accTemp[0] += imuData->acc_reg[0];
        accTemp[1] += imuData->acc_reg[1];
        accTemp[2] += imuData->acc_reg[2];
        gyroTemp[0] += imuData->gyro_reg[0];
        gyroTemp[1] += imuData->gyro_reg[1];
        gyroTemp[2] += imuData->gyro_reg[2];
    }
#endif

    switch(imuData->verticalDirection)
    {
    case ICM_VERTICAL_Z:
        printf("ICM Z Axis Is Down\r\n");     
#if 1                                // Convert value 
        imuData->accOffset[0] = accTemp[0] * 0.001;
        imuData->accOffset[1] = accTemp[1] * 0.001;
        imuData->accOffset[2] = (accTemp[2] * 0.001) - 8192.0;

        imuData->gyroOffset[0] = gyroTemp[0] * 0.001;
        imuData->gyroOffset[1] = gyroTemp[1] * 0.001;
        imuData->gyroOffset[2] = gyroTemp[2] * 0.001;
#endif
        break;

    case ICM_VERTICAL_Y:
        printf("ICM Y Axis Is Down\r\n");
        imuData->accOffset[0] = accTemp[0] * 0.001;
        imuData->accOffset[1] = (accTemp[1] * 0.001) - 8192.0;
        imuData->accOffset[2] = accTemp[2] * 0.001;

        imuData->gyroOffset[0] = gyroTemp[0] * 0.001;
        imuData->gyroOffset[1] = gyroTemp[1] * 0.001;
        imuData->gyroOffset[2] = gyroTemp[2] * 0.001;
        break;

    case ICM_VERTICAL_X:
        printf("ICM X Axis Is Down\r\n");
        imuData->accOffset[0] = (accTemp[0] * 0.001) - 8192.0;
        imuData->accOffset[1] = accTemp[1] * 0.001;
        imuData->accOffset[2] = accTemp[2] * 0.001;

        imuData->gyroOffset[0] = gyroTemp[0] * 0.001;
        imuData->gyroOffset[1] = gyroTemp[1] * 0.001;
        imuData->gyroOffset[2] = gyroTemp[2] * 0.001;
        break;
    }
    printf("R %d %d %d \r\n", imuData->acc_reg[0], imuData->acc_reg[1], imuData->acc_reg[2]);
    printf("T %ld %ld %ld \r\n", accTemp[0], accTemp[1], accTemp[2]);
    printf("ACC X Offset:%d\r\n", imuData->accOffset[0]);
    printf("ACC Y Offset:%d\r\n", imuData->accOffset[1]);
    printf("ACC Z Offset:%d\r\n", imuData->accOffset[2]);
    printf("GYR X Offset:%d\r\n", imuData->gyroOffset[0]);
    printf("GYR Y Offset:%d\r\n", imuData->gyroOffset[1]);
    printf("GYR Z Offset:%d\r\n", imuData->gyroOffset[2]);
    imuData->offsetFlag = 1;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain, what "wrong" means exactly. Does it always show 0, is it always ruoghly the half of the expected value, is it positive, while it should be negative?
Often the error behaviour hints you to where to look for the error itself...

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. The angle I get is always the wrong value such as 25.0 degrees instead of 90.0 degrees (real value)